# How to do branch to branch auto deploy using github

Tags: github

I am a **newbie** on git. How it possible to do auto deploy with branching on github. I have a github account and repository in it. I want to implement auto deploy like

- When committing  to branch "test" it will auto deploy to server 1
- When committing  to branch "production" it will auto deploy to server 2.

When I checking github webhook it will trigger only when committing to master branch only.

- Can I add a webhook for each branch
- How can I implement this.

I am using ec2 instance as web server.

Comment: There are many ways. I let Codeship handle it for me.